# failed to load file amd-ucode/micrcode_amd.bin kickstart vm

Tags: virtualization, kickstart

new kickstart iso.. when I restart my ubunutu server I get the following error ubuntu failed to load file amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin I tried to search for the file on my "regularly" installed ubunutu-server but I couldn't find it.. and I don't get the error message when I reboot it

Answer (score 1):

The package is named [`amd64-microcode`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/admin/amd64-microcode)

Contents:

```
/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin
/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/copyright
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/microcode_amd.bin.README
/usr/share/doc/amd64-microcode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin.README
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/amd64-microcode
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/amd64-microcode
```

So a

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
```

should fix that error if it failed to install during the installation.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package amd64-microcode